# What is a vtable in C++

Tags: c++, vtable

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [why do I need virtual table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3004501/why-do-i-need-virtual-table)

What is a vtable in C++?

So far I know that vtable is a virtual table which has an array of pointers to virtual functions.  Is there an article I can read with an example of a practical implementation?  (Any walk through will be appreciated.)

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_method_table

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2173493/virtual-table-c

Comment: Unless you plan to write a compiler this information is not relevant to understanding C++.

Comment: It's too bad this one is considered the duplicate.  The accepted answer on this question is better than the one on the "original".

Answer (score 52, accepted):

V-tables (or virtual tables) are how most C++ implementations do polymorphism. For each concrete implementation of a class, there is a table of function pointers to all the virtual methods. A pointer to this table (called the virtual table) exists as a data member in all the objects. When one calls a virtual method, we lookup the object's v-table and call the appropriate derived class method.

Comment: If your base class Foo has a virtual method, then your derived class Bar will have a vtable and the linker will check for that (if missing it says, undefined reference to `vtable for Bar')

Answer (score 6):

vTable (*virtual table*) is an implementation detail of dynamic dispatch (`virtual` methods).

See [C++-Lite-Faq](http://www.dietmar-kuehl.de/mirror/c++-faq/virtual-functions.html) for more details.

Comment: Broken link, please update or remove.

Comment: @donturner IMHO downvoting was rude. Googling C++ Lite Faq gives the page as second result. You could saved me end others trouble by editing the response yourself.

After all, the answer is 7 years old.

Comment: @phadej link only answers are frown upon for this exact reason: an external resource can move or be delete or changed and an answer here need to be self-sufficient.

Comment: Link Works! Very Good Article!

Comment: This is the very definition of a link-only answer.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/20313345)

Comment: @CalvT I'm very tempted to search the history of guidelines, when the link-only note was introduced. MetaQuestion https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92505/should-i-flag-answers-which-contain-only-a-link-as-not-an-answer

Comment: @phadej I counter your meta post with one of my own - [Should I flag old not-an-answers?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/120658/should-i-flag-old-not-an-answers).

Comment: @CalvT cant you just remove whole question as it's marked as a duplicate. I really don't care improving this answer. Added a sentence though. Hopefully makes you happy.

Comment: @CalvT also the question is "Is there an article with practical implementation?"

Comment: @phadej then the question is off topic. If you have a problem with me and four others thinking that your answer is not an answer, then by all means write up a meta post and I'll gladly change my views based on the outcome of that. I get this is an old question and answer, but all questions and answers on the site should fit within todays guidelines, not the guidelines of when they where posted.

Answer (score -2):

For all it's worth, it is not a standard C++ terminology. It is just an implementation detail used by the implementation to implement virtual functions/dynamic binding

Comment: It's not terminology of the standard, or standardized at all, but it is quite a standard term. Anyway, this would be better as a comment as it doesn't attempt to answer the question.