# How do compilers handle interfaces under the hood?

Tags: assembly, interface, compiler-construction

At a high level, I understand that an interface is a way of saying

> Just do this, I don't care how

In other words, it basically allows you to program declaratively instead of imperatively. You make your code more flexible when parts of it can tell other parts of it what to do, not how to do it.

I grok that concept when it comes to high-level languages like Java.

However, I am curious how *compilers* deal with interfaces. This may be a bigger question than I realize.

Here's my theory: It's based upon an offset in RAM.

As an example, when an object is created that implements the `ICompare` interface which includes the `Compare` method, then the compiler knows to put that `Compare` method at a 16 byte offset of where that object starts in RAM. In fact, every object that implements the `ICompare` method has its `Compare` method at the 16th byte. That way, when other code uses that interface to call the `Compare` method, the system knows to perform the instructions at the 16th byte of that object.

Is that how a compiler handles interfaces (using a standard location in every object) or does it use some kind of lookup table to know where an object's `Compare` method is? Or some other method entirely?

Comment: So the high level answer is to research 'vtables'. There are ways to optimize out vtables, but in general that's the concept you're looking for.

Comment: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vancem/2006/03/13/digging-into-interface-calls-in-the-net-framework-stub-based-dispatch/

Comment: Great comments, thank you. This answer was helpful for me to understand vtables better : https://stackoverflow.com/a/3555290/2363207. And this comment was interesting at the MSDN link: ".NET IL defines something called a MethodImpl Table which is a table that for a class, maps interface methods to method implementations."

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else interested in this question, [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Eaz0P_gJ9FE) is an EXCELLENT video with a visual explanation of how vtables are actually implemented in C++. The first four bytes of an object can point to a vtable that points to the correct method to use for that particular class.

Thanks @sircodesalot for the tip.

Comment: An object with virtual member functions can be stored anywhere; static, automatic (stack) or heap (dynamically allocated.  It always still has an implicit `vtable` pointer as the first member regardless of where it's stored.  See also [How do objects work in x86 at the assembly level?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33556511/how-do-objects-work-in-x86-at-the-assembly-level)

Comment: Excellent answer on that post, thank you for the link. I love when answers give you bite sized snippets of code that succinctly prove a point. It shows they were very well thought out. Thanks!